# Splitting string into groups of specific length

Tags: python, list

I was wondering what the best way to split up a string such as `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` into a list of groups of 2 (splitting the string into: `["ab", "bc", "cd", ... "yz]`) is in Python.

Or what about in groups of 3: splitting the string into `["abc", "bcd", "cde", ... "xyz"]`

Thanks!

Comment: @jamylak, The groups the OP is asking for are _overlapping_

Comment: @gnibbler Agreed, I was viewing an illusion of the examples

Answer (score 4):

Here is one that works for any iterable

```
>>> from itertools import tee, izip, islice
>>> chunksize = 2
>>> s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> t = tee(s, chunksize)
>>> for i, j in enumerate(t):
...  next(islice(j, i, i), None)
...
>>> ["".join(k) for k in izip(*t)]
['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef', 'fg', 'gh', 'hi', 'ij', 'jk', 'kl', 'lm', 'mn', 'no', 'op', 'pq', 'qr', 'rs', 'st', 'tu', 'uv', 'vw', 'wx', 'xy', 'yz']
```

If `s` is always a `str`, this is more straight forward

```
>>> [s[i: i + chunksize] for i in range(len(s) + 1 - chunksize)]
['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef', 'fg', 'gh', 'hi', 'ij', 'jk', 'kl', 'lm', 'mn', 'no', 'op', 'pq', 'qr', 'rs', 'st', 'tu', 'uv', 'vw', 'wx', 'xy', 'yz']
```

Comment: I just realized my method is basically the same as yours except I have mine set up like `pairwise`

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-liner:

```
def split_by_len(text, chunksize):
    return [text[i:(i+chunksize)] for i in range(len(text)-chunksize+1)]
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `str` as a name since it's a built-in. Probably `text` is a better name.

Comment: No, OP wants `["ab", "bc", "cd", ... "yz]`, not `["ab", "cd", "ef", ... "yz]`. And for triplets you get: `['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz']` ... the last element is too short.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> groups = zip(s, s[1:], s[2:])
>>> ["".join(g) for g in groups]
['abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def', 'efg', 'fgh', 'ghi', 'hij', 'ijk', 'jkl', 'klm', 'l
mn', 'mno', 'nop', 'opq', 'pqr', 'qrs', 'rst', 'stu', 'tuv', 'uvw', 'vwx', 'wxy'
, 'xyz']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def segment_string(s, segment_len):
    return [s[i:i+segment_len] for i in range(len(s) - (segment_len - 1))]

>>> for i in range(5):
        print segment_string("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", i)
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef', 'fg', 'gh', 'hi', 'ij', 'jk', 'kl', 'lm', 'mn', 'no', 'op', 'pq', 'qr', 'rs', 'st', 'tu', 'uv', 'vw', 'wx', 'xy', 'yz']
['abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def', 'efg', 'fgh', 'ghi', 'hij', 'ijk', 'jkl', 'klm', 'lmn', 'mno', 'nop', 'opq', 'pqr', 'qrs', 'rst', 'stu', 'tuv', 'uvw', 'vwx', 'wxy', 'xyz']
['abcd', 'bcde', 'cdef', 'defg', 'efgh', 'fghi', 'ghij', 'hijk', 'ijkl', 'jklm', 'klmn', 'lmno', 'mnop', 'nopq', 'opqr', 'pqrs', 'qrst', 'rstu', 'stuv', 'tuvw', 'uvwx', 'vwxy', 'wxyz']
```